# How do events and event objects work in amp-story? Is there a full list of AMP events and actions? Is there a full list for amp-story?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, amp-html, amp-story

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/amp-building-accelerated/9781786467317/d236e811-756a-4ffb-8f8b-712a34b8f751.xhtml

> So far, the only event we've seen is tap, and the only actions we've seen are open, close, and dismiss. You might be curious about what others are available. While tap applies to all elements, most events in AMP are specific to particular elements. For example, forms have submit , submit-success, and submit-error events, and input elements have a change event , while amp-selector has a select event, to name a few. There are many more; for a full list of AMP events and actions, see Appendix B, Actions and Events.
>
> Event Objects
>
> When an event occur in HTML, the event belongs to a certain event object, like a mouse click event belongs to the MouseEvent object.
>
> The Event Object
>
> All event objects are based on the Event Object, and inherits all of it's properties and methods

**common event objects**

- AnimationEvent   For CSS animations
- ClipboardEvent   For modification of the clipboard
- DragEvent    For drag and drop interaction
- FocusEvent   For focus-related events
- HashChangeEvent  For changes in the anchor part of the URL
- InputEvent   For user input
- KeyboardEvent    For keyboard interaction
- MouseEvent   For mouse interaction
- PageTransitionEvent  For navigating to, and away from, web pages
- PopStateEvent    For changes in the history entry
- ProgressEvent    For the progress of loading external resources
- StorageEvent     For changes in the window's storage area.
- TouchEvent   For touch interaction
- TransitionEvent  For CSS transitions
- UiEvent  For user interface interaction
- WheelEvent   For mousewheel interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full list for AMP generally can be found in the [AMP Actions and Events documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/amp-actions-and-events).

For AMP stories, there are currently no events supported.